# Why am I unable to get a specific ID from this array of IDs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, indexing

I'm using an NPM package called Twit to get a list of IDs that follow a specific twitter user

```
T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'kanyewest' },  function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

outputs:

```
root@box:/var/app/twitterbot# screen -r twitterbot
     793990194311626800,
     902628660292837400,
     937381447303823400,
     966061750650069000,
     143239761,
     396278761,
     949690872429387800,
     880529987392204800,
     142651429,
     31053983,
     757696951659921400,
     879346525666762800,
     1651454588,
     927660101279903700,
     737929151907287000,
     933093234590466000,
     114504331,
     1104837235,
     ... 4900 more items ],
  next_cursor: 1598483705781998800,
  next_cursor_str: '1598483705781998810',
  previous_cursor: 0,
  previous_cursor_str: '0' }
```

However, if I do:

```
T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'kanyewest' },  function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data[1])
})
```

I get undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(data, response)`;

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Too long to paste here https://pastebin.com/Cnti1Fqx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an object, not an array, the ids are available at `data.ids` which is an array of ids

```
T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'kanyewest' },  function (err, data) {
   console.log(data.ids)
});
```

The package has an [example](https://github.com/ttezel/twit/blob/master/examples/bot.js#L82) on github where you can see how it's used.

Comment: @LouisVuittonDon if it worked, remember to accept the answer